# Definition of graph's copy and associated question

Tags: graph-theory

My first question is a basic one. What is the copy of the graph? I researched many sites and books and didn't find any definition.

My main question is associated with this term: how many copies of graph $K_x$ we can find in graph $K_y$ assuming that $1\leq x\leq y$? I would appreciate any advices.

Answer (score 1):

The question is probably about [subgraph isomorphism](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Subgraph_isomorphism_problem)

**Subgraph Isomorphism Problem:**

Two graphs G and H are given as input, and one must determine whether G contains a subgraph that is isomorphic to H

Finding the number of copies of a graph $K_x$ in $K_y$ is exactly that.

Copy of a graph is just an informal term for a graph isomorphism.

Comment: Thanks. So is it a number of bijective transformations?

Comment: Yes. Consider a simple example of a subgraph $K_3$ (https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Gallery_of_named_graphs#/media/File:Complete_graph_K3.svg), If you find one isomorphism, there are others you can find as well due to symmetry of $K_3$, eg: rotations of $K_3$

Comment: Do you know how to count directly? I know only that the number of all functions from $x$ to $y$ is equal to $y^x$, but it does not help a lot.